# How to get upper/lower parts of a numpy array relative to 45 degree diagonal?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to figure out how to get the upper and lower triangles of a numpy matrix relative to the 45 degree diagonal from lower left to upper right.  In other words, if my numpy array is

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
```

I want arrays containing [1,2,3],[4,5],[7] in one (with or without the diagonal) and [6],[8,9] in the other.

I know that `np.triu` and `np.tril` split the array along the other diagonal (from upper left to lower right), but I can't seem to figure out how to do it along the lower left to upper right diagonal.

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: `np.triu(a[::-1])[::-1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if there are direct functions that achieve this but you can always rely on list slicing.
So prepare a list of rows and columns based on whether the element is in right or left of array,
then set the sliced array value as 0.
The opposite of array can be taken by subtracting the first and spitted array

Finally here is my code

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
b=a.copy()
r=[i for i in range(0,a.shape[0]) for j in range(0,a.shape[1]) if j>a.shape[1]-i-1 ]
c=[j for i in range(0,a.shape[0]) for j in range(0,a.shape[1]) if j>a.shape[1]-i-1 ]
a[r,c]=0
print('left',a)
a=b-a
print('right',a)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.fliplr` to reverse the order of elements along left-right axis which will turn the anti-diagonal into the diagonal, and then use the usual `np.triu` and `np.tril`.